# My OpenCV feed is lagging and I want to make it smoother

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, keras, google-text-to-speech

**I'm making my research project and an amateur at tensorflow and OpenCV, I am trying to make a sign-language translator with real-time text-to-speech feature. I made the others work, but my OpenCV cam feed is laggy and is a bit hard to follow through because of it. I was hoping on what to do to optimize it.**

Here is my Live-feed code:

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np
from gtts import gTTS
import threading
from queue import Queue
import pyttsx3
import time

# Initialize OpenCV VideoCapture
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

frame_count = 0
frame_skip = 3  # Process every 3rd frame

# Initialize MediaPipe Holistic model
mp_holistic = mp.solutions.holistic
holistic = mp_holistic.Holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.65, min_tracking_confidence=0.5)

# Initialize text-to-speech engine
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.setProperty('rate', 150)  

# Initialize a thread-safe queue for text-to-speech requests
speech_queue = Queue()

# Function to handle text-to-speech
def text_to_speech_worker():
    while True:
        text_to_display = speech_queue.get()
        if text_to_display:
            engine.say(text_to_display)
            engine.runAndWait()
            time.sleep(5)  
            speech_queue.task_done() 

# Start the text-to-speech thread
tts_thread = threading.Thread(target=text_to_speech_worker)
tts_thread.daemon = True
tts_thread.start()

current_word_index = 0
words_to_display = ['hello', 'how are you', 'thank you', 'im fine']

# Other variables
sequence = []
actions = np.array(['hello', 'how are you', 'thank you', 'im fine'])
sentence = []
predictions = []
threshold = 0.6
last_action = None

while cap.isOpened():
    frame_count += 1
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        continue

    # Skip frames based on frame_skip value
    if frame_count % frame_skip != 0:
        continue

    # Perform holistic detection
    with mp_holistic.Holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.65, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic:
        image, results = mediapipe_detection(frame, holistic)

    # Prediction logic
    keypoints = extract_keypoints(results)
    sequence.append(keypoints)
    sequence = sequence[-30:]

    # Modify prediction logic to ensure `res` is a list of probabilities
    if len(sequence) == 30:
        res = model.predict(np.expand_dims(sequence, axis=0))[0].tolist()
        action = actions[np.argmax(res)]
        print(action)
        predictions.append(action)

        if np.unique(predictions[-10:])[0] == action:
            if res[np.argmax(res)] > threshold:
                if last_action != action:
                    sentence.append(action)
                    last_action = action

        if len(sentence) > 4:
            sentence = sentence[-4:]
        
        # Check if it's time to change the displayed word
        if current_word_index < len(words_to_display):
            text_to_display = words_to_display[current_word_index]
            speech_queue.put(text_to_display)
            current_word_index += 1

        # Visualize the probabilities and display the sentence on the OpenCV frame
        image = prob_viz(res, actions, image, colors)
        text_to_display = ' '.join(sentence)
        speech_queue.put(text_to_display)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (0, 0), (640, 40), (245, 117, 16), -1)
        cv2.putText(image, text_to_display, (3, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

    cv2.imshow('OpenCV Feed', image)

    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried using frame-skipping to enhance the performance, but it did not work.
I tried multithreading, I don't understand how it works, so I didn't delve too much in it.
I did adjust the resolution to a new_width, new_height = 640, 480, it lessened the framerate a bit, but still not smooth.